# Parameter is not valid. Stack Trace at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Stream stream)

Tags: c#, bitmap, stream, arrays, memorystream

For some cases only i'm getting this error. "Parameter is not valid Stack Trace   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Stream stream)" i am little confused how it is working for some records why not for other. Anyone please guide me to find my mistake will be very helpful..,

Following are my codes.,

```
private void RefreshImage()
    {
        if (this.dsPatPhoto.dmDoc.Count <= 0) return;

        byte[] patImage = null;
        byte[] driverLicImage = null;

        foreach (CmData.WrCmDoc.DsCmDoc.dmDocRow row in this.dsPatPhoto.dmDoc)
        {
            if (!row.IsIDDocTypeNull() &&
                row.IDDocType == (short)AppCommonCfg.DocType.PatientDriverLicense)
            {
                if (!row.IsDocImageNull())
                    driverLicImage = row.DocImage;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!row.IsDocImageNull())
                    patImage = row.DocImage;
            }
        }

        System.IO.MemoryStream stream;
        if (patImage != null && patImage.Length > 0)
        {
            stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(patImage, true);
            this.ucPictureEditPic.Clear();
            this.ucPictureEditPic.Image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(stream);
        }

        if (driverLicImage != null && driverLicImage.Length > 0)
        {
            stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(driverLicImage, true);
            this.ucPictureEditDL.Clear();
            this.ucPictureEditDL.Image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(stream); //Error occurs here.
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is the image stored in the dataset a valid image? If the constructor can't figure out how the byte data is structured, it won't be able to construct an image from the bytes. If you load the bytes from a known file and compare it to the bytes from the dataset do they match? See also the [Bitmap reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Bitmap.cs,167).

Comment: @theB-Thanks for the reply-But i'm not sure my image is invalid. If it is a corrupted image means what i can do.., Is there any way to convert it into valid image.  By code can we make it possible??

Comment: From the reference source it looks like the bitmap class uses GDI+ to create images. There are  7 GDI errors that can cause the constructor to throw an `ArgumentException` 1) Invalid Parameter, 2) Unknown Image Format, 3) Property Not Found, 4) Property Not Supported, 5-7) Assorted Font Issues. Given the description of the issue, I'm willing to eliminate all but #2. If you save the data from the dataset to a file, can you open that file in an image editor? (IE - use `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes()` to dump the byte array to a file when you get the exception.)

Comment: @theB-sorry for asking can you post a sample code will be very helpful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Bitmap.cs,167) we can see that the bitmap class is using GDI+ native methods for constructing the image. From the reference source we can also see the [list of exceptions](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/Gdiplus.cs,4edcade52d698713) that the constructor could possibly throw. Out of all the exceptions that can be thrown there are 8 places where an ArgumentException could be coming from.

1. Stream is null.
2. Invalid Parameter.
3. Unknown Image Format.
4. Property Not Found.
5. Property Not Supported.
6. Font Family Not Found.
7. Font Style Not Found.
8. Not True Type Font.

We can eliminate #6-8 immediately since you're not trying to render a font. We can also eliminate #1 since the stream object is being created immediately above the call to the bitmap constructor. Numbers 2, 4 and 5 are a little more complex to evaluate but I've eliminated them as possibilities since memory streams are valid for constructing bitmaps. (I use it often as a go to method for rendering web based images.)

This leaves us with the unknown image format. There are two ways to check that the byte array is valid.

1. Load a copy of the image from a file and compare the bytes to those from the `DataSet`.

   ```
   if (driverLicImage != null && driverLicImage.Length > 0)
   {
       byte[] knownGoodImage = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("Path to good file on disk");
       if (!driverLicImage.SequenceEqual(knownGoodImage))
       {
           // now you know that the bytes in the database don't match
       }
       stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(driverLicImage, true);
       this.ucPictureEditDL.Clear();
       this.ucPictureEditDL.Image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(stream); //Error occurs here.
   }
   ```
2. Catch the constructor exception and save the file to disk so you can try to open it with a image editor. (Like MS Paint)

   ```
   if (driverLicImage != null && driverLicImage.Length > 0)
   {
       try
       {
           stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(driverLicImage, true);
           this.ucPictureEditDL.Clear();
           this.ucPictureEditDL.Image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(stream); //Error occurs here.
       }
       catch (ArgumentException ex)
       {
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(ex.Message);
           System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("Filename", driverLicImage);
       }
   }
   ```

   Of course you will want to choose an appropriate file name.

Comment: @theB-Thank u so much. You saved me a lot. Actually that byte value is not an image type it is a pdf file. but i was came to know this while writing the bytes into txt. Now i solved my error. Your help is really appriciated